# I am trying to take an input in python 2.7 and allow it to distinguish between strings and integers

Tags: python, input, user-input

I'm new and tried the search function but couldn't find an appropriate method and would appreciate any support possible.

I would like to amend this code to allow user input of a number or word. If Var a and b are numbers, the code will test for an int and compare the size of the numbers, however if a word is selected it will test for a string and print string involved. I am trying to keep the code fairly simple.

```
varA = raw_input('Enter a number or string ')

varB = raw_input('Enter a number or string ')

if type (varA) == str or type (varB) == str:

    print "string involved"
elif varA > varB:
    print "bigger"
elif varA == varB:
    print "equal"
elif varA < varB:
    print "smaller"
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601703/how-to-take-different-input-types-and-do-something-different-with-each-python-3

Comment: `varA` and `varB` will always be strings, as that is what `raw_input()` returns. If you want to cast one or the other to an integer, use `int()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use var.isdigit() to check if your string variable is also a number. You can then cast the other choices using int(var).

Note, if you check to see if both are a number first, you don't need the error handling.

See code below:

```
 def main():
    varA = raw_input("Enter a number or string") #this is a string by default   
    varB = raw_input("Enter a number or string")

    aNegDigit = False
    bNegDigit = False
    stringFlag = False #used to flag strings (e.g. -abc)

    if(varA[0] == "-" and varA[1:].isdigit()):
        varA = -1*int(varA[1:])
        aNegDigit = True

    if(varB[0] == "-" and varB[1:].isdigit()):
        varB = -1*int(varB[1:])
        bNegDigit = True

    if (aNegDigit or bNegDigit):
        if(not(aNegDigit)):
            if(varA.isdigit()):
               varA = int(varA)
            else:
                stringFlag = True

        if (not(bNegDigit)):
            if(varB.isdigit()):
               varB = int(varB)
            else:
                stringFlag = True

        if (stringFlag == True):
            print("String Involved")

        else:
            compareVarStrs(varA, varB)

    elif(varA.isdigit() and varB.isdigit()):
        compareVarStrs(varA, varB)

    else:
        print("String Involved")

def compareVarStrs(varA, varB):
    if (int(varA) > int(varB)):
        print ("bigger")

    elif (int(varA) < int(varB)):
        print ("smaller")

    else:
        print ("equal")

main()
```

Comment: Thanks this works for most examples, apart from two negative numbers that aren't the same. If I input varA = -1 and varB = -5 it prints smaller instead of bigger. Is there any way to get it to convert negative numbers accurately to ints?

Comment: @neoraiden Someone must have deleted all of my comments. However,  this issue is now resolved :). Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    varA = int(varA)
    varB = int(varB)
except ValueError:
    print 'invalid input'
```

1. The returned value of `raw_input` is of type `str`
2. What you want is checking whether there's a number in the `str` object returned
3. Eventually you are going to convert these `str`s to `int`s so that you can compare, so why not just go ahead and try to convert it first:

Comment: Note that `"   1"` converts to `int` with no problem, but `.isdigit()` returns `False`.

Answer (score -1):

Floam's response wouldn't work because of his 'if' condition. If EITHER one of the inputs are digits (one could be a string) it will try to compare characters with digits. That will cause inaccurate results if it even runs.

*Update* I initially wrote it in the wrong syntax

Try this:

```
varA = raw_input('Enter a number or string ')
varB = raw_input('Enter a number or string ')

if varA.isdigit() and varB.isdigit():
    varA = int(varA)
    varB = int(varB)

    if varA > varB:
        print "bigger"
    elif varA == varB:
        print "equal"
    elif varA < varB:
        print "smaller" 

else:
    print "strings involved"
```

Comment: This is a Python question. I'm not even sure if the code you wrote is valid in any language, but it certainly ain't Python.

Comment: Thanks this works for most examples, apart from two negative numbers that aren't the same. If I input varA = -1 and varB = -5 it prints smaller instead of bigger. Is there any way to get it to convert negative numbers accurately to ints?

Comment: @neoraiden - Change the initial if statement `if not varA.isalpha() and not varB.isalpha():` I was having a problem if it interpreting the negative-sign as a character, which made the `isalpha()` method return a false... causing the if-statement to think the vars are strings.